# Why can't I use variable names as same as class name?

Tags: c++

The following gives me an error:

```
struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    foo foo;
    foo foo2;
}

main.cpp:14:9: error: expected ';' before 'foo2'
     foo foo2 = foo;

main.cpp:14:19: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     foo foo2 = foo;
```

Yet `foo foo, foo2` works perfectly fine. What rule prevents me from doing the first way?

All of you are either downvoting or leaving rude comments instead of answering the question. I'm asking for the rule that is making the first way not compile.

Comment: The better question is why? At best it might compile and your collaborators will hate you. At worst you'll have terrible name shadowing problems that will be hard to debug.

Comment: "Why can't I just variable names as same as class name?" because its confusing as hell.

Comment: That's not the code you compiled. Give the real code.

Comment: I take it you're an avid fan of [How to Write Unmaintainable Code](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)?

Comment: The language allows you to have data members same as class name, so why not variables in block scope?

Comment: you don't want to program in C++, you want to invent and then use language `foo` which has only one keyword and one valid name for *everything* ;)

Comment: @Cyber You can use an elaborated type specifier to make the first way compile, so what's your point?

Comment: @user4105736 My point is, even if you come up with a way for it to compile, it is a stupid idea. Period.

Answer (score 6):

The declaration of object foo the name of which coincides with the name of the structure hides the name of the structure.  So in the following declaration

```
foo foo2;
```

the compiler considers name `foo` as the name of the object instead of the name of the structure. To escape the error you could use elaborated name of structure foo. For example

```
struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    foo foo;
    struct foo foo2;
}
```

By the way the following funny declaration is valid:)

```
struct foo { int foo; } foo, foo2 = foo;
```